# Gremlin: text searching predicates not working on OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have the below query on OrientDB:

```
g.V().hasLabel('people').has('firstName',startingWith('V')).values('ID')
```

And I am getting a "Failed executing Gremlin query" response. I know there are 'people' with first name that start with "V", but even if there weren't it should return empty results. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running OrientDB version 3.0.x which is aligned to Gremlin 3.3.x.

These new text predicates, like `startingWith`, where added in Gremlin 3.4.x, and available in OriendDB version [3.1.x](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.1.x/release/3.1/), which is currently in milestone preview.